# Kazaam how to stop recording?

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I just installed Kazaam but I can't figure out how to stop this thing from recording. There is no button or dialog anywhere which I can press to stop recorind. Any ideas? I use 14.04 with gnome.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Ubuntu Forums thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2253301) this problem is specific to GNOME. The pause button doesn't show up or appears in a strange place.

The solution posted there was to install the [TopIcons extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/).

Comment: Happens also on KDE.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a keyboard shortcut like Super-Control-F, which brings up the Kazam dialog for what to do with the finished capture.

See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/415424/296434

Comment: This does not work as the shortcuts for Kazam are not global, so whenever a focus on the window is lost, they stop working. Kazam is simply a bad piece of software.